# Does MySQL Queue Stored Procedure calls?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have a stored procedure sp_performArchive() which calls another stored procedure multiple times.  Like so -

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_performarchive`()
BEGIN
CALL sp_archive2('pallets', 4);
CALL sp_archive2('cases', 4);
CALL sp_archive2('prepacks', 4);
CALL sp_archive2('bottles', 4);
END
```

I am having some oddities in my data, which would be explainable if they these sp_archive2's were running concurrently.  Is that the case here?  Does MySQL try to run them all at once?  Or are they put into a queue?

I am using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: I'd say - "procedures" are procedural. So what "oddities" do you have in your data?

Comment: The sp_archive2 data runs on 4 tables of which there is a hierarchy structure, each bottle has a prepack, each prepack has a case, each case has a pallet.  I am seeing things where prepacks are not archived, but their parent case is and child bottle is.  This would happen if the child bottles got archived before that particular prepack was reached.  Which would be explained if these ran simultaneously.

Comment: it'd probably help if you include the code from sp_archive2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Each MySQL session is single-threaded, so there's no way one session can run those stored procedures in parallel. The statements in a procedure are executed serially.

You can still have race conditions, but it could happen only if you run the procedures in more than one session.